# Find $HK$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{21}^{\times}$

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

Find $HK$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{21}^{\times}$ if $H =\{[1],[8]\}$ and $K=\{[1],[4],[10],[13],[16],[19]\}$.

My attempt:

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
*& [1] & [4] & [10] &[13] & [16] &[19] \\ \hline
[1] &1 &4 &10 & 13 & 16 & 19\\ \hline
[8]& 8 & 11 & 17& 20 & 2 & 5\\ \hline
 \
\end{array}

Therefore $HK=\{1,2,4,5,8,10,11,13,16, 17,19,20\}=\mathbb{Z}_{21}^\times$.

Comment: First: is $\;\Bbb Z^x_{16}=\Bbb Z_{16}^*=$ the group of units in the ring $\;\Bbb Z_{16}\;$ ? If so, neither of $\;8,4,10,16\;$ belong to this group...and $\;19=3\pmod{16}\;$ .

Comment: it equals the group of relative primes to 16

Comment: typo, i meant to type 21 not 16

Comment: Exactly: then both $\;H,\,K\;$ aren't even susbets of it...

Comment: is it correct now @DonAntonio ?

Comment: Yes, I think it is...but I present you an idea in my answer to make it, perhaps, simpler and shorter.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that $\;\phi(21)=\phi(3)\phi(7)=2\cdot6=12\;$, and also that $\;H\cap K=\{1\}\;$ . Since we're in an abelian group, this automatically mean these two subgroups (**now** they are subgroups...) generate their own direct product, so

$$HK\cong H\times K\implies |HK|=|H|\,|K|=2\cdot6=12=|\Bbb Z_{21}^*|\implies HK=\Bbb Z_{21}$$